# Visual Studio Error al abrir proyecto ASP.NET MVC

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc

Saludos a la comunidad.

A ver si alguien me puede ayudar con el siguiente problema:

Cuando creo un proyecto ASP.NET MVC en un ordenador, lo guardo en mi pendrive y luego intento abrirlo en otro ordenador no se carga y aparece el siguiente error:

Falló la creación del directorio virtual https://localhost:puerto/ con el error: Archivo D:\VS2019\WebAppMvc.vs\WebAppMvc\config\applicationhost.config

Error: No se puede leer el archivo de confiuración

Necesita crear manualmente este directorio virtual en IIS antes de que pueda abrir el proyecto.

El problema se da tanto en visual studio 2017 como en 2019 y tanto en http como en https)

Modifico los archivos web.config también en y no se soluciona, también he intentado modificar en el archivo de proyecto .csproj

Gracias de Antemano.

Comment: Seguramente en tu pc usas el iis de Windows y al llevarlo a otra pc que no está instalado no te permite abrirlo lo que podes hacer es editar el archivo .csproj y busca iisexpress generalmente aparece al final cambia la variable a true y la del iis a false.

Comment: Gracias por contestar.Ese no es el problema. No tengo instalado el IIS de Windows. En las 3 máquinas trabajo con el IIS Express q viene con Visual Studio.

Comment: De todas maneras miré el .csproj y UseIISExpress estaba en False y UseIIS esrana también en false; cambié UseIIsExpress a true y tampoco se aregla el problema.

Comment: Antes de abrirlo en otra pc al proyecto elimina la carpeta .vs es un archivo oculto eso contiene info de proyecto de donde se estaba usando posiblemente ayude. Saludos

Comment: Ya lo hice también y nada.

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto.

El problema era que todos los intentos los hacía abriendo el proyecto desde una unidad de red, a pesar que le indicaba al VS que confiaba en dicha unidad de red.

Eliminando la carpeta .vs y copiando el proyecto a un disco local se solucionó.

Gracias Maximiliano por los esfuerzos.

Saludos